# Get Route with Variable Placeholder in ServiceStack (C#)

Tags: c#, servicestack

Good Morning,

I am attempting to get the original ServiceStack route meaning I want the route with the variable place holder not just the replaced route. Please see the examples below for more details

---

**Route with variable**

*/foo/{Name}*

However as part of the request filter I am only able to see

/foo/JDoe

is it possible to capture the italicized text as well as the replaced value? storing and capturing the route with the variable placeholder will be useful for turning routing on/off by route as well as, allowing us to also do a comparison on the expected route with the value that gets replaced visually as well. I am using C# and ServiceStack version="3.9.71" targetFramework="net40" in this project. Thanks... Please let me know if you need more details or anything is unclear.

~ Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was added in ServiceStack v4 where you can get the matching route definition with:

```
var route = base.Request.GetRoute();
route.Path.Print(); //= /foo/{Name}
```

Comment: Thanks, mythz. I appreciate the answer and will definitely keep this in mind for future. Unfortunately I am not able to upgrade this project to v4 at this time, still I appreciate the simplicity to do this in the new version, thanks again.